# Low memory copy throughput Host to Device

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have a vector of vectors `vector<vector<double>> data`.
I want to copy only the information contained in that "2D matrix" as there are no vectors in CUDA.
So the first approach I used was

```
vector<vector<double>> *values;
vector<vector<double>>::iterator it;
double *d_values;
double *dst;

checkCudaErr(
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_values, sizeof(double)*M*N)
);

dst = d_values;
for (it = values->begin(); it != values->end(); ++it){
    double *src = &((*it)[0]);
    size_t s = it->size();
    checkCudaErr(
        cudaMemcpy(dst, src, sizeof(double)*s, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
        );
    dst += s;
}
```

After profiling with NVVP I got a very low cudaMempcpy throughput. I think this is logic as I'm sending a very small amount of
bytes in each cudaMemcpy call.
So I decided to change a little bit the code to try to improve this, so the second approach is

```
double *h_values = new double[M*N];

dst = h_values;
for (it = values->begin(); it != values->end(); ++it){
    double *src = &((*it)[0]);
    size_t s = it->size();
    memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(double)*s);
    dst += s;
}

checkCudaErr(
    cudaMemcpy(d_values, h_values, sizeof(double)*M*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
);
```

the result after profiling is still a low memcpy throughput.
So, my question is, how can I improve the copies from host to device?

I'm using a Quadro K4000. I'm getting 25 MB/s for the first case and about 2 GB/s on the second one. M = 5 and N = 2000000. I must say the value for M is a common value, but sometimes it can get up to 50.

Comment: You should be more exact - I think you dont mean your memcpy throughput is low, but your cudaMemcpy throughput is low, right? To help you you should also say which GPU you have and what the actual throughput is, and the size of your M and N.

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant `cudaMemcpy` (I just copy what the nvvp profiler says). I just edited the question.

Comment: How does M and N map to the original vector? Does it mean that you have 2000000 vectors of 5-50 entries each to copy or the reverse. And you state that the second case is giving you 2Gb/s per second transfer on a 80Mb transfer. How does that compare to the performance of the standard HostToDevice bandwidth test that comes with CUDA?

Comment: M-rows, N-cols. Yes, Nvidia's visual profiler reports a 2GB/s on average for the second case, should I use `nvprof` instead?. For the pageable memory transfer test I got about 3.7GB/s, so I could say I'm getting about 50% of the available Bandwidth.

Comment: What kind of transfer rate do you get if you run your own bandwidth measurement on this particular `cudaMemcpy` call using cudaEvents ?

Comment: I did the measurements and I'm getting around 4.7 GB/s in the first case and 6.7 GB/s on the second one. The problem is that the overall time of my algorithm using GPU is more than it actually is on CPU. It takes more time `cudaMemcpy+pinnedMemory` (I have to copy from vector to pinned memory to GPU). Anyway, my question was answered by @flolo .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reason for your slow throughput can be that you allocate your double matrix with new. This memory is not page locked. You can either use a system function (dont know which system you use) or the cuda function providing this functionality. It would be `cudaMallocHost`.

Just remove your `=new double[M*N]` and set your `h_values` with `cudaMallocHost(&h_values, sizeof(double)*M*N)` (and of course dont delete it, but free it (with `cudaFreeHost`)).

Btw. the theoretical top speed is 8 GB/s (PCI 2.0 x 16 lanes), practical you will stay below it (around 6 GB/s).

Comment: It is worth noting that pinning host memory isn't free - there is rather a high API and host kernel overhead in doing so. It might be that while the *transfer* using pinning memory is faster, the overall execution time of the code might not improve if there is only a single transfer involved

Comment: 8GB/s is the peak theoretical bandwidth of a PCIe 2.0 x16 link (per direction).  It is not realizable in practice for a variety of reasons.  I have never seen a measurement substantially higher than 6GB/s, and 6GB/s can only be achieved with pinned transfers.  You cannot expect to ever measure or observe 8GB/s for a unidirectional transfer on PCIe 2.0 x16, of actual data payload.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: You are absolutly right, I edited the answer to make it clear.